# Reading from a separate file to get the Spring DataSource Credentials in yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, datasource, credentials

I have a credentials file that is located at a different directory location than my jar.  In it is the Username and Password I need to connect to my DataSource so I can run my Batch job.  The Spring-Batch job is set up to read its datasource info from a yaml file.  As such I am wandering how I can pull the username and password from the credential file and put it into the Spring.dataSource.username & password variables on the yml file without needing to create some java method.  I tried to test it with the below code but it was never able to pull the username or password.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

YAML file

```
spring:
  config:
    additional-location: C:/accessInfo.credentials
  datasource:
    username: ${access.user}
    password: ${access.password}
```

Credentials File

```
access.user=user
access.password=password
```

Comment: The property is called `spring.config.location` where did you get `additional-location` from?

Comment: I was looking through the Spring Documents on Common Application Properties ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html ) and I saw the additional-location tag along with the  location tag and the additional-location tag seemed more appropriate.  I just wanted to make sure I was using it right.